# Fetch data and display in ListView Parse.com

Tags: string, android-studio, parse-platform

I am trying to pull a string `"newStatus"` on parse.com and display it in a list view called `Post Status`. I am already able to save a `"newStatus"` string from my app.

[image: here is parse database]

Now, when text is input and `"posted"` on my app, it refreshes the post page, where I have a `"listview"` implemented, and after refreshing, I want it to display all the `"newStatus"` strings in the list view.

I will post code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Either fetch the updated PFObject from Parse
- Or when the post to parse succeeded update you listview data source

Option 1 would look like :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Status");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
   if (e == null) {
  // object
      String status = object.getString("newStatus");
   } else {
  // error
  }
 }
});
```